# wp-cli: wp term generate xxxxx - Error: 'xxxxx' is not a registered taxonomy

Tags: wp-cli

I'm writing a WP CLI command which creates and updates taxonomies using `wp_insert_term`. Actions on my custom taxonomies are not accepted since they don't show up as registered.

The wp-cli included [Term_Command](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/2ad47776f13cac8cf14c3ba669036b378f879cf1/php/commands/term.php) itself uses `wp_insert_term` and allows actions on default taxonomies but errors on custom taxonomies.

Various searches suggest custom taxonomies aren't registered until `init`. Is there a way to run `init` inside wp-cli so custom taxonomies can be manipulated? Anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way, although it feels a bit wrong.

First test if the taxonomy exists (which it doesn't… the first time at least), and then create it as part of the process…

```
if (! taxonomy_exists($this->taxonomy_manufacturer)) {
     register_taxonomy($this->taxonomy_manufacturer, 'product');
}

if (! term_exists($manufacturer['name'], $this->taxonomy_manufacturer)) {
     wp_insert_term($manufacturer['name'], $this->taxonomy_manufacturer);
}
```

Caveat, [register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) warns of [impending doom](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15568) if it's called outside of `init`. I'm not sure of the implications of it in my scenario, and I'll report back if my spideysense starts tingling, but so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a multisite, you have to specify the site you are running the command for using --url so that it will load the correct theme.

For example

```
wp --require=check-vehicle-fallback.php vehicle-fallback export --url=yoursite.example.dev
```